# File reader doesn't load first time - VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, filereader

I have a problem with a file reader, it load the file never the fist time, and it's like a queue. I mean: it start from the second time I select a file but it upload the first.

Can I solve this?

Here the code.

```
        <v-text-field
          v-if="switch1"
          label="Upload Fattura"
          @click='onPickFile'
          v-model='fatturaFileName'
          prepend-icon="mdi-paperclip"
        ></v-text-field>
        <input
          type="file"
          style="display: none"
          ref="fileInput"
          accept="text/xml"
          @change="onFilePicked"
        >


  onPickFile () {
    this.$refs.fileInput.click();
     }`

 onFilePicked (event) {
      if (event) event.preventDefault();
      var files = event.target.files[0];
      if (files !== undefined) {
        this.fatturaFileName = files.name;

        // If valid, continue
        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.readAsText(files);
        fr.addEventListener('load', () => {
          this.fatturaUpload = fr.result;
        });
      } else {
         this.fatturaFileName = ''
         this.fatturaFileObject = null
      }
      console.log(this.fatturaUpload);
  }
```

Comment: i think you should do something like `fr.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
          this.fatturaUpload = e.target.result;
        });`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim nothing changed.

Comment: What about `fr.onloadend = () => {this.fatturaUpload = fr.result}` ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim always the same. Check here with a xml file: https://codepen.io/cenzowm/pen/bGbrOBd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine using the following code  :

```
onFilePicked (event) {
      if (event) event.preventDefault();
      var fichier = event.target.files[0];
      if (fichier != undefined) {
           const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.readAsDataURL(fichier);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        let file = fichier;
        reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
        reader.onload = evt => {
            console.log("1",evt.target.result)
        };
      } else {
        console.log("2",fichier)
         this.fatturaFileName = ''
         this.fatturaFileObject = null
      }
      console.log("3",this.fatturaUpload);
       this.fatturaFileName = '';
       this.fatturaFileObject = null;

    }
```

See the Pen 
  [Vuetify Template](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/wvwqRda/) by boussadjra ([@boussadjra](https://codepen.io/boussadjra))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Can I have always (even the first time) the right value in a var? Because I need it!

Comment: i didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: In this way I can print the right value, but it will be always "" out of the load scope!!

Comment: reader.onload = evt => {
          ciccio = evt.target.result;
          console.log("1",evt.target.result)
        };

I want a variable with the result out this peace of code

Comment: you could assign  `this.fatturaUpload= evt.target.result` after `console.log('1',...)` and add computed property based on this value in order to keep that reactive

Comment: I think the main problem is filereader is async

Comment: yes, for this you need another computed property based on `this.fatturaUpload`

Comment: What I have to put in this computed property?

Comment: something like parsing the content of `this.fatturaUpload`

Comment: Can u show me a little example on codepen?

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/wvwqRda?editors=0011 and use that property in future needs like rendering content in DOM like `<p>{{parsedContent}}</p>`

Comment: But I need it in JS not in the dom!

Comment: where ? please provide an use case

Comment: https://codepen.io/cenzowm/pen/bGbrOBd?editors=1111

Comment: why don't you put that logic inside async callback ?